# Is Kattappa bound to serve whoever sits on Throne even usurpers and forceful conqueror?

Tags: character, baahubali-the-beginning

Kattappa is royal guard and serves to Mahismati's king as his ancestors has taken vows to serve the kingdom generation after generations. It is shown in movie that Kattappa continue to serve Bhallala Deva who is keeping previous queen Devasena. There is a dialogue where Bhallala says I know it despises you to serve me.We know that Bhallala is a usurper who gained the throne instead of Baahubali and don't care much for the kingdom or people.

Does it means he is bound to serve whoever sits on Throne or in other words is kind of Mahishmati. Let's assume some other king like King of kalakeyas (who attacked the kingdom and lost the war), conquores the Mahismati and become king, then Kattappa will serve him loyally given that Kalakey don't kill him.

Comment: I believe Kattappa probably would have served Kalakey too, he said it himself that he is a slave of the throne. Even though he is a great warrior himself, he is bound to serve the king. He mentioned it after his sword fight with the middle eastern king if you remember. If my sources are reliable and the story I have heard is true than I would say wait for the 2nd part, the story is different and really interesting. A lot of your doubts will be cleared until then people would be giving answers based on pure speculation.

Comment: If you can add the quotes where he said he bound to Throne and will serve whoever is on that throne, then this is not speculation. You can add it as answer answer, and i will like accept it. Unless someone comes up with something else with more concrete citation.

Comment: I could find a Hindi print of the movie on you tube at 26:00 mins if you see https://youtu.be/CdTU8E5xXQs . I do not know if you speak hindi at all. But basically Kattapa tells the middle eastern king that his forefathers are forever bound to serve mahishmati throne. No amount of money can buy his freedom from the king. If you satisfied with this than I can make it an answer.

Comment: As of now i don't have access to you tube . I will check it later. However you can make it answer, I will accept it. And I know hindi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the conversation between Kattappa and the middle eastern king, the king offers to buy Kattappa his freedom to which Kattappa refuses saying that no money in the world could buy his freedom.

His fore fathers have vowed to protect the kingdom of Mahishmati and he would die serving the king as a slave to keep his promise.

Well this is a poor attempt at translation from hindi to english by me of the entire dialogue, but here is the link to the full movie in Hindi where you can see the discussion somewhere around 26 mins in to the movie.

[Baahubali full movie](http://youtu.be/CdTU8E5xXQs)

Thus I believe that Kattappa would serve the king no matter who he is. Even if it is Kalekey

Answer (score 0):

In one of the initial [promotional videos](https://youtu.be/9szsE6mc4-M), you could find that Bhallaladeva sitting on the thrown, while Amarendra Bahubali(saying by the minister sitting on the front row) is swinging the sword. In another frame you would find the younger Bhallaladeva rising from the thrown and shouting out Bahuali. In both the frames Shivagami is not visible. So Bhallaladeva might have somehow got the throne. But still it does not justify Kattapa killing Bahubali, since he was ready to rescue Devasena, by going against kings order in the first half.

Facts are
1. Bahubali and Devasena conceive a baby
2. Devasena is captured by Bhallaladeva

Might be like in Mahabaratha, Kumsa tries to kill newly born lord Krishna but is rescued from the jail and also is crossed from the river, similarly Shivagami rescuses newly born Shivudu from jail where Devasena is captured. Might be some how Shivagami is involved in jailing Devasena and Bahubali tries to get her out by starting a rebellion and Kattapa has to kill Bahuabli to rescue Bhallaladeva(existing king). Might be the scar on his(Bhallaladeva's) face is also in the fight between them.

But its bad predicting the story, was expecting Kattapa to say Bhallaladeva's name in the end when asked who stabed him, since in the first half Bhallaladeva tells Devasena that there are only two people in this kingdom who remember Babhuabli's name, "you and me", me so that I could kill him once again. Might be he was talking about Shivudu or after stabing by Kattapa, Bhallaladeva kills bahubali.
[![enter image description here][2]][2][image]

Comment: How is this relevant to question , I have asked ? It seems you are trying to answer about death of Bahubali, however I have not asked that

Comment: Though your answer is not related to question, but your assumption related to bahubali2 is just fabulous.